# Moving an unnamed hash in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I created an array in perl called @jobs.  Its an array to hold hashes of my job lists.

I populate it and sort into another array with the following code:

```
open(my $JOBLIST, '<:crlf', 'Jobs.conf') 
    or die "Unable to open file, $!";

#Store Hashes into jobs array

while (<$JOBLIST>) {
    push(@jobs, {split(/:\s*|\n/)});
}

#sort jobs array by JobArrival

my @sortJobs = sort { $a->{JobArrival} <=> $b->{JobArrival} } @jobs;
```

How do I access the hashes in @sortJobs and move them to other arrays etc?  I understand how to push but I don't think that these hashes are named so i'm unsure how i access them?

EDIT for clarity:

My jobs.conf file looks like:

```
JobName: A
JobSize: 100
JobArrival: 4
JobExe: 100

JobName: C
JobSize: 100
JobArrival: 2
JobExe: 100

JobName: B
JobSize: 100
JobArrival: 3
JobExe:100

JobName: D
JobSize: 100
JobArrival: 1
JobExe: 100
```

When i have have sorted it, my array of hashes looks like this:

```
[
  { JobArrival => 1, JobExe => 100, JobName => "D", JobSize => 100 },
  { JobArrival => 2, JobExe => 100, JobName => "C", JobSize => 100 },
  { JobArrival => 3, JobExe => 100, JobName => "B", JobSize => 100 },
  { JobArrival => 4, JobExe => 100, JobName => "A", JobSize => 100 },
]
```

What i need to do is take the first job from that array "D", and move it to another array.  Once i've done that I need to access the next one and move that, etc until I have moved all of the hashes from this array.

Normally i would use the hash name but as far as i can see these hashes are unnamed and that is confusing me.

Comment: Accessing the hash references themselves is simple (`$sortJobs[ $some_index ]`). Are you asking about how to access the fields in the hashes? What does the `Jobs.conf` look like?

Comment: @Kenney  I updated the main post hopefully it makes my intentions clearer.

Comment: A little, thanks - just missing some details about where you want to put the hashes - based on what condition etc. I think you could just `shift` the first hash from the sorted list and put it somewhere else - but that's probably too trivial?

Comment: I'm trying to make a simulation "memory manager" for my university assignment.  so basically I want to take this list of sorted jobs and move it to an array called @queue.  I just looked it up and I think shift will work.  So I would just type @queue(shift @sortJobs)? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy `@sortJobs` into a new `@queue` you could simply do

```
@queue = @sortJobs;
```

To move the elements, you could do

```
while ( @sortJobs ) {
    push @queue, shift @sortJobs;
}
```

These are identical, except that `@sortJobs` will be empty in the second case.

Here we use the [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) function to remove one element from the 'head' of the array, and [push](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) to append it.

Note that it doesn't matter what's in `@sortJobs` - could be scalars, hashrefs, arrayrefs, etc..

Here's one more example, illustrating how to access the data in the hashrefs, to put them in different queues:

```
while ( @sortJobs ) {
   my $jobRef = shift @sortJobs;             # $job is a hashref
   my %job    = %{$jobRef};                  # dereference it to a normal hash

   if ( $jobRef->{JobName} == 'D' ) {        # using the hashref
       push @myDQueue, $jobRef;
   } elsif ( $job{JobName} == 'C' ) {        # using the hash 
       push @myCQueue, $jobRef;
   } else {
       push @myNormalQueue, $jobRef;
   }
}
```

Much more on this in [PerlRefTut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I need.  How can I do this with one hash at a time instead of moving the entire contents at once?

Comment: That's what the `while` is for - the `push @queue, shift @sortJobs` only moves 1 element.

Comment: Thank you very much @kenney